# how to get the result of ampl solvers as an array in python

Tags: python, optimization, ampl

I am using ampl for modeling my optimization problem in python and I am beginner in ampl. My variable is a two dimensional array. This is my data:

```
 data;
set USER := u1 u2 ; 
set JOB := j1 j2 ;
param p:= 
u1 j1 0.8022422666444835
u1 j2 0.8022422666444835
u2 j1 0.8022422666444835
u2 j2 0.8022422666444835
; 
param o:= 
u1 j1 0.268
u1 j2 0.544
u2 j1 0.234
u2 j2 0.964
;
```

and this is my ampl modeling:

```
set USER;
set JOB;

param p {USER,JOB}>=0;
param o {USER,JOB}>=0;

var t {i in USER, k in JOB}>=0;

maximize profit: sum{k in JOB} 50*log(1+(sum{i in USER} log(1+t[i,k]*o[i,k])))-sum{i in USER}sum{k in JOB} t[i,k]*p[i,k];
```

The result will be `t` variable. I want to convert `t` to a two dimensional array in python because I want to use the result of this optimization problem in my python code.
I ran this code in python:

```
time = ampl.getVariable('t')
for i in time:
    print(i)
```

and the result is:

```
(('u1', 'j1'), <amplpy.variable.Variable object at 0x7f82b3b419d0>)
(('u1', 'j2'), <amplpy.variable.Variable object at 0x7f82b3b41d10>)
(('u2', 'j1'), <amplpy.variable.Variable object at 0x7f82b3b41b50>)
(('u2', 'j2'), <amplpy.variable.Variable object at 0x7f82b3b41b10>)
```

I don't know how can I convert this result to a two dimensional array in python. Could you help me pleas? 
Thanks for your helps in advance.

Comment: It occurred to me you might have wanted to have something indexed by the u1 and j1 etc values, so you could do lookups like `data["u1"]["j2"]`. If so you want a dict of dicts rather than the answer I have below which makes a list of lists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python there are 2 things commonly used which are array like, `lists` and `tuples`. The main difference is that a tuple can not be altered, but a list can. For example you can append to the end of a list. But you can't add or delete items from a tuple.

The value of the `time` variable you have in your python code is something that can be iterated over and which yields a tuple of two tuples at least for the output you have shown us. The first of the two tuples has two items.

Presuming the same pattern holds, and that you want a list of lists of the three items in each iteration over this time variable this should work:

```
time = ampl.getVariable('t')

list_of_lists = []
for param, ampl_var in time:
    u_value, j_value = param
    list_of_lists.append([u_value, j_value, ampl_var])

for sub_list in list_of_lists:
    print(sub_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
time = ampl.get_variable('t').get_values().to_list()
print(time)
```

They didn't write these methods in the documentation but you can trace it back simply with an IDE. Normally use control+LMB on the thing you want to trace back.